# C Program Structs Assignment Invalid Octal Digit

Tags: c, date, struct, digits, octal

> Program Specifications:
>
> DESIGN and IMPLEMENT a program that will CREATE and use three
>   different variables of type PERSON.
>
> Create a struct using the typedef command for a DATE.
>
> Create a struct for a PERSON with the following fields.
>
> name [this will be a string] birthdate [this will be a DATE] gender
>   [this will be a char] annualIncome [this will be either float or
>   double, your choice] Create three variables of type PERSON.  Create a
>   function that populates the data for each person (all 3 of them). 
>   Create a function that outputs all data about each of the people in a
>   nice formatted manner.
>
> Data Validation:
>
> All dates entered must be validated.  Make sure you account for the
>   number of days in each month, the fact that there are exactly 12
>   months and every four years there is a leap year.
>
> The name for each PERSON will be stored in sentence case.
>
> The gender will either be M, F, or O.
>
> The annual income will between 0 dollars and 1 million dollars.

```
   /*Programmer: John B.*/
/*Date: 2/26/19*/
/*Program to demonstrate structs for a date and person with specified fields.*/
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define CLS system("cls")
#define FLUSH nothingFlush()

void nothingFlush() {
    char nothing;
    while (scanf("%c", &nothing) == NULL);
}

typedef struct {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} DATE;

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    char lastName[100];
    DATE dob;
    char gender;
    float anualIncome;
} PERSON;

//Prototype Functions
void displayDate(DATE birthday);
void displayWorkers(PERSON wOne, PERSON wTwo, PERSON wThree);
DATE getDate();
float getAnualIncome(PERSON *wOne, PERSON *wTwo, PERSON *wThree);
void getThings(PERSON *wOne, PERSON *wTwo, PERSON *wThree);

//Main
main() {
    DATE birthday;
    PERSON workerOne, workerTwo, workerThree;

    getThings(&workerOne, &workerTwo, &workerThree);
    displayWorkers(workerOne, workerTwo, workerThree);

    PAUSE;
}//End Main

//Write Functions
void displayDate(DATE birthday) {
    printf("\n\t%i/%i/%i\n", birthday.month, birthday.day, birthday.year);
}//End Display Date

void displayWorkers(PERSON wOne, PERSON wTwo, PERSON wThree) {
    CLS;

    strcpy(wOne.name, "Austin");
    strcpy(wOne.lastName, "Warner");
    strcpy(wTwo.name, "Lee");
    strcpy(wTwo.lastName, "Cousins");
    strcpy(wThree.name, "McKinley");
    strcpy(wThree.lastName, "Alitolof");

    printf("\n\tFirst: %s\n", wOne.name);
    printf("\n\tLast: %s\n", wOne.lastName);
    displayDate(wOne.dob);
    printf("\n\tGender: %c\n", wOne.gender);
    printf("\n\tAnual Income: %.2f\n", wOne.anualIncome);

    printf("\n\tFirst: %s\n", wTwo.name);
    printf("\n\tLast: %s\n", wTwo.lastName);
    displayDate(wTwo.dob);
    printf("\n\tGender: %c\n", wTwo.gender);
    printf("\n\tAnual Income: %.2f\n", wTwo.anualIncome);

    printf("\n\tFirst: %s\n", wThree.name);
    printf("\n\tLast: %s\n", wThree.lastName);
    displayDate(wThree.dob);
    printf("\n\tGender: %c\n", wThree.gender);
    printf("\n\tAnual Income: %.2f\n", wThree.anualIncome);

}//End Display Workers

float getAnualIncome(PERSON *wOne, PERSON *wTwo, PERSON *wThree) {
    float result;

    do {
        printf("\n\tEnter The Anual Income Of The Worker: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &result); FLUSH;
        if (result < 0 || result > 1000000)
            printf("Invalid Number--- Try Again\n");
    } while (result < 0 || result > 1000000);

    return result;
}

DATE getDate() {
    DATE result;

    do {
        printf("\n\tEnter Year: ");
        scanf_s("%i", &result.year); FLUSH;
        if (result.year < 1900 || result.year > 5000)
            printf("\tInvalid Number--- Try Again\n");
    } while (result.year < 1900 || result.year > 5000);

    do {
        printf("\n\tEnter Month: *****Please enter single digit months as a single digit***** ");
        scanf_s("%i", &result.month); FLUSH;
        if (result.month < 0 || result.month > 12)
            printf("\tInvalid Number--- Try Again\n");
    } while (result.month < 0 || result.month > 12);

    do {
        printf("\n\tEnter Day: ");
        scanf_s("%i", &result.day); FLUSH;
        if (result.day < 1 || result.day > 31) {
                printf("\tInvalid Number--- Try Again\n");
        }
        if (result.month == 2 || result.month == 02) { //Check for leap year
            if (((result.year % 4 == 0) && result.year % 100 != 0) ||
                (result.year % 400 == 0)) {
                while (result.day < 1 || result.day > 29) { //Leap year feb dates 1-29
                    printf("\tLeap Year--- Try Again\n");
                    printf("\n\tEnter Day: ");
                    scanf_s("%i", &result.day); FLUSH;
                }
            }
            else {
                while (result.day < 1 || result.day > 28) { //Leap year feb dates 1-29
                    printf("\tInvalid Number--- Try Again\n");
                    printf("\n\tEnter Day: ");
                    scanf_s("%i", &result.day); FLUSH;
                }
            }
        }

        if (result.month == 4 || result.month == 04 || result.month == 6 || // Check if month has only 30 days
            result.month == 06 || result.month == 9 || result.month == 09 || result.month == 11) { //Invalid Octal Digit??
            while (result.day < 1 || result.day > 30) {
                printf("\tInvalid Day--- Try Again\n");
                printf("\n\tEnter Day: ");
                scanf_s("%i", &result.day); FLUSH;
            }
        }
    } while (result.day < 1 || result.day > 31);

    return result;
}//End Get Date

char getGender(PERSON *wOne, PERSON *wTwo, PERSON *wThree) {
    char result;
    do {
        printf("\n\tEnter The Gender For The Worker: ");
        scanf_s("%c", &result); FLUSH;
        if (result != 'F' && result != 'f' && result != 'M' && result != 'm' && 
            result != 'O' && result != 'o')
            printf("\n\tERROR-- Try Again...\n");
    } while (result != 'F' && result != 'f' && result != 'M' && result != 'm' &&
        result != 'O' && result != 'o');

    return result;
}//End Get Gender

void getThings(PERSON *wOne, PERSON *wTwo, PERSON *wThree) {
    CLS;

    printf("\n\tEnter The Date Of Birth Of Austin: \n");
    wOne->dob = getDate();
    wOne->gender = getGender(&wOne, &wTwo, &wThree);
    wOne->anualIncome = getAnualIncome(&wOne, &wTwo, &wThree);

    printf("\n\tEnter The Date Of Birth Of Lee: \n");
    wTwo->dob = getDate();
    wTwo->gender = getGender(&wOne, &wTwo, &wThree);
    wTwo->anualIncome = getAnualIncome(&wOne, &wTwo, &wThree);

    printf("\n\tEnter The Date Of Birth Of McKinley: \n");
    wThree->dob = getDate();
    wThree->gender = getGender(&wOne, &wTwo, &wThree);
    wThree->anualIncome = getAnualIncome(&wOne, &wTwo, &wThree);

}//End Get Things
```

So my program runs pretty solid, but I do get an error saying Invalid Octal Digit because of result.month == 09 (where it checks if its a month with only 30 days, Line 139). I was including single digit months as both 9 and 09 in case people put them in that way. And it didn't become an issue until i got above 7. How do I fix this to allow the month to be entered as either 9 or 09. Currently when someone enters 09, the value for result.month is 0 or some weird number, it doesn't stop the number from being entered and allows the days for 09 to be 31 when it should only be 30. Hopefully this is clear enough for someone to understand, and I tried to provide as much info as possible.  Thanks for they help!

Comment: Get rid of all of the numbers with a 0 at the beginning, unless you purposefully mean an octal number. `result.month == 09` is invalid in base-8. If you want to allow a leading zero you'll have to handle input as text and parse it appropriately.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Write answers instead of comments.

Comment: Note that `%i` can lead to unexpected results when people enter dates in August or September.

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled (at least `-W3`.  The results may surprise you.

Comment: @Swordfish Figured it would get closed as typo or too broad. It's also kinda rambly and feels like a morpher. Someone else jumped on the grenade. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja chux isn't someone likely to jump on grenades.

Answer (score 0):

The `0` in `result.month == 09` begins an *octal integer constant* yet the rest (`9`) is not octal.  Hence the coding error.  Use `result.month == 9` instead.

Change `scanf_s("%i",...` to `scanf_s("%d",...` to read input only a decimal.

Other problems may exist.